I have multiple folders with parquet files in an S3 bucket, is there an AWS service I could use to infer schema of parquet files in those folders
I have multiple folders with parquet files in an S3 bucket each representing a table at the source. Is there an AWS service I could use to infer schema of parquet files in those folders and be able to query the data without writing code?
I would also like to add an exclusion pattern to exclude some folders and files which are parquet files

I would say it depends on where you want the data to be seen, but for most cases I would use Glue it has great integrations like Redshift, Athena, etc. but you need to manually create your table.
Another solution can be Athena, which support connections directly to Quicksight and Apache Spark and it also can infer the columns, but it runs with Glue, so I would say it is worth it only if you really don't want to manually create the table. Another not so cool about athena is that only infers by sampling a very small part of the data you give it, so if only one parquet files has extra columns, or all parquet files have different columns, you may encounter problems with the result of your data.
Lastly, if you are dumpling data from time to time to redshift, and do not need anything automatic, you can just copy it by doing:
COPY listing
FROM 's3://mybucket/data/listings/parquet/'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
FORMAT AS PARQUET;

I would say you must use Glue if you want to access all files and exclude some others. Unless you want a lot of athena queries which can be pricey.

Thank you for your reply. I used crawlers on sample data in the S3 bucket and it correctly inferred the schema of parquet files when I queried the data using Athena. Am I correct in my understanding from your reply above that even by using crawlers there is good chance of missing columns?

Yes, Athena does a very small sampling of the data, it grabs only a small number of files to infer the columns, so if you have 2 o 3 files with different columns between GB of data there is a very big chance that those columns won't appear. It happened where I work where some columns in dynamodb were not appearing because of this sampling, and those columns not being always present.

As soon as u have a glue crawler it makes a glue table, and any glue table can be queried from redshift using spectrum, which just uses Athena under the hood
